# iTerm+ssh mouse actions suddenly showing text instead

Tags: ssh, iterm

Basically what the title says.  Something changed and I can't figure out what, and I made a new iTerm profile.

When I do anything with my mouse in an ssh connection in iTerm (scrolling, trying to select text, etc), instead of the actions occurring I get text like:

```
> 65;50;28M65;50;28M65;86;46M65;17;50M32;
```

etc.

Never had this happen before, any ideas?

Comment: Try `View` > `Allow Mouse Reporting`

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunately